# Can summoned creatures be attacked?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, summoning

I have two friends who play as the Druid and Cleric and they both have summoning powers. We got confused as to whether the summoned creatures (such as a guardian drake) can be targeted by monsters or enemies because the power doesn't say anywhere that they have hit points or what their AC is. Animal companions do have ht points and AC listed, which makes me think summons don't have them on purpose.

Do these summoned creatures just stay on the field for the entire encounter or can they somehow be dissipated when a creature hits them?

Comment: Can you specify the power being used to summon the creatures.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this discussion](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2658766),

> Unless otherwise stated, a summoned creature's maximum hit points
>   equal your bloodied value.  If it drops to 0 hit points, it is
>   destroyed and you lose a healing surge.  If you have no surges to
>   lose, you take damage equal to half of your bloodied value.  Its
>   defenses equal your defenses when you summon it, not including any
>   temporary bonuses or penalties.

All the summons [listed here](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Summoning_(4e_Mage_School)) explicitly state that each time.